# Is there a redux for dart middleware for api calls to a service

Tags: flutter, dart, redux

I have a small flutter app using redux for dart.
I am currently using redux_thunk for asynchronous actions and it works very well. Except that my async actions so far only contain dummy code like this:

```
void action(Store<String> store) async {
  final searchResults = await new Future.delayed(
    new Duration(seconds: 1),
    () => "Search Results",
  );

  store.dispatch(searchResults);
}
```

Now I would like to call a method in a service (e.g. Firestore) but the thunk actions only take the store as an argument. So how would I pass the service into the actions?

Was wondering since I couldn't find any examples of a good pattern.

I found this: https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/blob/master/firestore_redux/lib/middleware/store_todos_middleware.dart

But it has all async actions as part of the middleware which I don't particularly like.